# Get date from date picker to string in a variable

Tags: ios, swift, datetime, uidatepicker

I have making and order app I have take an `outlet` named: `selectedDate` and I want to retrieve the selected date to a variable. What should I place in View did load.

```
@IBOutlet weak var selectedDate: UIDatePicker!

func datePickerChanged(selectedDate:UIDatePicker) {
    var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.FullStyle
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.FulltStyle
    var strDate = dateFormatter.string(from: selectedDate.date)  
}
```

Comment: place current date. selectedDate.date = Date()

Comment: datepicker.date gives you the date instance. in picker view delegate methods you will get the changed date.

Comment: Please go through  apple documentation   https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uidatepicker

Comment: What do you mean by **"What should I place in View did load."**?

Comment: `nsstring` is NOT a relevant tag for this question as it has been proposed in an edit - we are using swift strings, not NSStrings...

Comment: Elaborate your question. what do you want by place in view did load ?

Comment: I have this code for getting the date from datepicker so I am not sure I have / or have not to include something in viewdidload

Comment: @Dory suggest me if there should be included in viewdidload

Comment: datePickerChanged is delegate method, which observers date change in picker.. you only need to set delegate instance in viewdidLoad.

Comment: yes, updating in answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
 @IBAction func datePickerChanged(sender: UIDatePicker) {

    print("print \(sender.date)")

    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd, YYYY"
    let somedateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)

    print(somedateString)  // "somedateString" is your string date
}


}
```

You have to create a IBAction for datePicker and name it as “datePickerChanged” , just like you create outlet of object.  Choose connection type "Action" when you are dragging object to Viewcontroller.

Comment: if you are satisfied with answer, can you please accept it.. Might help others.

Answer (score 3):

`func datePickerChanged(_:UIDatePicker)` is a target function.

Did you set the target correctly ?

```
// Precise that our controller implement the delegate
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
  ...
  @IBOutlet weak var selectedDate: UIDatePicker!
  ...
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ...
    selectedDate.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerChanged(_:)), forControlEvents: .valueChanged) // We register the target function
  }

  ...
  // We implement that function
  func datePickerChanged(sender:UIDatePicker) {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .full
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .full
    let strDate = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)  
    print(strDate)
  } 
}
```

Comment: use of undeclared type 'UIDatePickerDelegate' error

Comment: value of type dateformatter has no member 'FullStyle' error

Comment: @Solangi Code that you have added in question is some were else or you are using it?

Comment: it is in view controller not inside any method

Comment: I have corrected, my mistake, there is no delegate for DatePicker. But the way to do it is to add a target method to a value changed. Please try that :)